# How to free C struct value memory in cgo with python?

Tags: python-3.x, go, cgo

What would be the best way to free the value of the C struct or the struct created in cgo (shared lib) in python?

Go code:

```golang
//export getResponse
func getResponse() C.Resp {
    // b := C.CString(Response.respBody)
    // defer C.free(b)

    return C.Resp{
        response: C.CString(Response.respBody),
    }
}

//export freeResponse
func freeResponse(response *C.char) {
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(response))
}
```

Py code:

```py
def Free(ptr):
    free = lib.freeResponse
    free.argtypes = [c_char_p] #c_void_p
    free(ptr)

class Resp(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('response', c_char_p)
    ]

lib.getResponse.restype = Resp
r = lib.getResponse()
print(r.response)
Free(r.reponse)
```

This would crash py charm and give an error.

Comment: What is `lib.free` here?

Comment: In either case, basically it rolls like this: `C.C*` functions provided by `cgo` call `malloc()` of whatever `libc` which gets linked with the poduced Go library. `C.free` calls `free()` of that same `libc`. Now if you can guarantee that both your Python-side C code and your Go library _link with the same instance of `libc`,_ you're golden and can just call `free` from `libc` on the Python side. If you cannot do this, it's best to export from your Go library function (or functions) for explicit deallocation; for instance, export `freeResponse` to be called to clean up after `getResponse`.

Comment: How can you know if they both link with the same instance of libc?

Comment: Also when I export a free function that I made from cgo. I get a ```malloc: *** error for object 0xc0000ae038: pointer being freed was not allocated``` and ```malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug``` then my pycharm crashes

Comment: I edited the code so that you have a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: «How can you know if they both link with the same instance of libc?»—for instance, by producing a dynamically-linked library out of both your Go code and your Python C module so that they get linked to the same `libc` at runtime.

Comment: I have no idea about the Python side, but I've just tested in with plain C, and it works: https://gist.github.com/kostix/10c80b61a32cd2f4fd2dcc6b1c317ca2